# Drawing rectangle on top of data using patches

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to draw a rectangle on top of a data plot in `matplotlib`. To do this, I have this code

```
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

...

fig = pl.figure()
ax=fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.add_patch(
patches.Rectangle(
        (776820, 5000),   # (x,y)
        3000,          # width
        3500,          # height
        fill=False
    )
)
ax.plot(signal)
ax.plot(fit)
...
```

When I do this, the rectangle is behind the data, however. It doesn't appear to matter if I add the rectnagle before or after plotting the actual data. How can I ensure that the rectangle is the top-most element in the figure?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The matplotlib.patches.Rectangle allows the keyword argument **zorder** that is by default 1.0.

Choosing a zorder above one should bring your rectangle to the foreground of the image.

```
ax.add_patch(
patches.Rectangle(
    (776820, 5000),   # (x,y)
    3000,          # width
    3500,          # height
    fill=False,
    zorder=2
    )
)
```